# Giving users access to images located in an Iphone application

Tags: iphone, ios

First of all just let me say that this is my very first attempt at making an ios app so if everyone would treat me as a complete noob I would appreciate it.

After searching here and Google for 2 hours I decided to just ask, I realise that I've probably missed it somewhere so please don't bite my head off if it's located elsewhere.

So I was asked to design a gallery app for an artist where users could preview his work and then buy packages of high resolution images if they wanted. what I did was created one "main" free app with thumbnails of all the art organised into galleries. Each gallery has a purchase button which will link to a seperate app containing the high res images of that gallery. My problem is thus, I want to give users full access to the images. I.E. I don't want them to just be able to view them in app, I want them to be able to use the jpg's for whatever they want (wallpaper, websites, etc, etc).

What would the best way to do this? Add them to the iphone / ipad's gallery app? Just an external folder containing the images? And also how would one go about doing it, remember I built this entire thing using just the interface builder and have no idea how to code in objective c at all so please take this into account when responding.

Thank you in advance for any help, I'm getting desperate and the artist is getting impatient.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action

Comment: You're also, apparently, a complete neophyte here on SO.  If you weren't you wouldn't have formatted your first paragraph as code when it plainly isn't.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark me?

Comment: @Kobe.o4, no, OP, hence lack of @.

Comment: I taught it was me, sorry. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to write some code (or find a programmer). It doesn't hurt (too much...)

Try looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301012/saving-images-to-iphone-photo-library) and see how far you get